# xcode 5 - app crashes when running in release build configuration

Tags: xcode, configuration

When I run my app in the debug configuration mode, it works ok. But when I change the scheme to use the release configuration mode, the app crashes, and xcode shows the following error:
process launch failed: failed to get the task for process 5712

I've tried to delete the app completely and run it in the release mode, but it didn't help. Does anyone know how can I run the app on my device from xcode in the release mode?

Comment: When you run the debug variant, are you running it in the debugger? Because debuggers typically clear local variables, meaning the pointers will be `NULL`, while otherwise the values of local variables are indeterminate (and will be seemingly random, most likely *not* zero, or `NULL`). So if you check an uninitialized pointer variable for `NULL` it will work fine in the debugger, but cause [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when not running in the debugger.

Comment: If you are running your app with appsync (without developer account) you have to use jailcoder with the xcode project :P

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm running it in the debugger. I press the product menu and then I hit "run". If I create a release version using menu -> archive, and load it to testflight, and then install it on my device, the app runs ok.

Comment: and I do have a developer account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking more into it, I think that it is not really a problem.
Xcode does crash when I try to run in the release mode, but it seems that it is able to install the app properly on my device. So after it crashes, if I get into the app, it works properly. I guess that this is because the release mode can't run with the xcode debugger.

Comment: Hi did you manage to debug the release mode with the debugger , I have an issue happening only in release mode but I dont know how to debug it :(

Comment: @jerem sorry, but I didn't manage to use the release mode with the debugger. BUT, I'm unaware of recent developments of xcode, so maybe things have changed since then.